# Unrecognized expression when having a string with curly braces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where one of the hidden input boxes is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RequestID" id="RequestID" value="{834b3866-6373-4f2d-8e0b-f28da66c3317}" />
```

in my jquery I want to get the RequestID like

```
$('#btnGetId').on('click', function(){
   var reqID = $('#RequestID').val();
   alert(reqID);
});
```

When running the code my console says:

> unrecognized expression {834b3866-6373-4f2d-8e0b-f28da66c3317}

this is because of the curly braces, so I tried this

```
var reqID = $('#RequestID').val(); reqID.replace(/[{}]/g, '\\$&');
```

When I run the code, my alert says:

> [object, object]

What I need is that I get the guid: {834b3866-6373-4f2d-8e0b-f28da66c3317} in my alert box but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Theres some other code generating that error that you're not showing us. See; works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/a4ek9z0n/

Comment: _"When running the code my console says:

`unrecognized expression {834b3866-6373-4f2d-8e0b-f28da66c3317}`"_ Can you create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: Yes, @Jamiec is correct. The code you posted could not have generated that error. It has to be some other code in your program. Your Console should give you a line number. That will indicate where the problem really is.

Comment: @Jamiec I've found it. apparently I had alert($(reqID)); in my Original code. So I've changed it and now it's working.

Comment: Great, I was just about to suggest it was in jQuery `$()`. Please answer your own question, or remove your question if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Original code I had:

```
$('#btnGetId').on('click', function(){
   var reqID = $('#RequestID').val();
   alert($(reqID));
});
```

I've changed it to

```
$('#btnGetId').on('click', function(){
   var reqID = $('#RequestID').val();
   alert(reqID);
});
```

Now it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use data-... attribute instead of value :

The Html becomes :

```
<input type="hidden" name="RequestID" id="RequestID" data-val="{834b3866-6373-4f2d-8e0b-f28da66c3317}" />
```

And the js becomes :

```
$('#btnGetId').on('click', function(){
   var reqID = $('#RequestID').attr("data-val");
   alert(reqID);
});
```

Demo here :

https://jsfiddle.net/7c48867q/3/

Comment: So was the original ;)